# Building a CRUD screens for many to many relationship in MVC 5 and EF 6.1

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am stuck trying to figure out how to build many to many relationship and give the user the proper form to enter the data. I have a Class object and I have an Teacher object, the Teacher can have many classes and the class can have many teachers I can't use check boxes as number of teachers we have is over 100 as well as the classes. my models as follow

```
 public abstract class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First name can not be longer than 50 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Last name can not be longer than 50 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Middle Initial")]
    public string MidInit { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Contact Number")]
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Work Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name = "Notes")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public int? ConsId { get; set; }
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            string firstName = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.FirstName) ? "" : this.FirstName;
            string midInit = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.MidInit) ? "" : this.MidInit;
            string lastName = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.LastName) ? "" : this.LastName;
            return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", firstName, " ", midInit, " ", LastName);
        }
    }    
}    
public class Teacher : Person
{
    public Teacher()
    {
        Classes = new HashSet<AClass>();
    }

    [Display(Name = "Classes Taught")]
    public virtual ICollection<AClass> Classes { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.PersonId.ToString();
    }
}
public class AClass
{
    public AClass()
    {
        Instructors = new HashSet<Teacher>();
        ClassEndDate = DateTime.Today;
    }
    public int AClassId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Class Number")]
    public string ClassNo { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Class Name")]
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Section Number")]
    public string SectionNumber { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Class Start Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime ClassStartDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm tt}")]
    [Display(Name = "Class Start Time")]
    public DateTime? ClassStartTime { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Class End Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime ClassEndDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Teacher> Instructors { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> ClassInstructorId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Teacher> AllInstructors { get; set; } 
    public string ClassDisplay
    {
        get
        {
            return ClassNo + " - " + ClassName + " Start Date: " + ClassStartDate.ToShortDateString();
        }
    }
}
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<AClass> Classes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<AClass>().HasMany<Teacher>(i => i.Instructors).WithMany(c => c.Classes).Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapLeftKey("AClassId");
            m.MapRightKey("PersonId");
            m.ToTable("ClassInstructor");
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("AspNetUsers").HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles").HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("AspNetUserRoles").HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

my crud create form I modified it to include multiselectlist is as follow

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>AClass</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClassNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClassNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClassName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClassName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SectionNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SectionNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SectionNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Teacher", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.ClassInstructorId, new MultiSelectList(Model.AllInstructors, "PersonID", "FullName"), new { Multiple = "multiple" })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClassStartDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClassStartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassStartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClassStartTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClassStartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassStartTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClassEndDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClassEndDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassEndDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

my classes controller is as follow for the Create action

```
       // GET: Classes/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        AClass model = new AClass();
        model.AllInstructors = db.Persons.OfType<Teacher>().ToList();
        model.ClassInstructorId = Enumerable.Empty<int>();
        foreach (Teacher inst in model.Instructors)
        {
            model.ClassInstructorId = model.ClassInstructorId.Concat(new[] { inst.PersonId });
        }
        model.ClassStartDate = DateTime.Today;
        return View(model);
    }

    // POST: Classes/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  //      public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "AClassId,ClassNo,ClassName,SectionNumber,ClassStartDate,ClassStartTime,ClassEndDate")] AClass aClass)
    public ActionResult Create(AClass aClass, )

    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Classes.Add(aClass);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(aClass);
    }
```

tables created successfully but my problem is how to assign the instructors to the classes when creating them also how to bring them back in the case of edits. any insights will be greatly appreciated. I though EF handle the related data.

Comment: You might need to show your controller code that does the update. I like to work these things out in a test script before I start working with the view.  As to the UI, there are various master(class)/detail(students) options out there involving simple tables or sophisticated grids like Kendo UI.

Comment: I updated the code with the multiselect list in the controller and the view but the relation table is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did and it worked like a charm Thanks for all your help and I hope this code could help some one else in my Place.

I changed the classId to Guid from int

then in my controller Post Method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(AClass aClass, )

{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        aClass.AClassId = Guid.NewGuid();
        aClass.Instructors = db.Persons.OfType<Teacher>().Where(m => aClass.ClassInstructorId.Contains(m.PersonId)).ToList();
        db.Classes.Add(aClass);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(aClass);
}
```

and entityframework took care of the rest.